# How can I determine which MERV filters would be best for my air handler?

Tags: air-conditioning

I have a Carrier 3.5 ton, 1/2HP air handler (`Model Number:fc4bnf042`).  I have been using MERV 13 a/c filters for a few years now because my son has allergies.  I recently discovered that the higher MERV filters can cause resistance that can strain the blower.  Does anyone know if there is a simple way of determining whether I am OK with the MERV 13?

Answer (score 2):

One [website](http://www.filtersamerica.com/air-purifier/central-air-cleaners/replacement-filters/carrier/) I found is selling filters in the same range as yours for that model.

Outside of checking with Carrier, though, I can't think of an absolute answer.