# What is the max MERV or MPR air filter that a 13 SEER HVAC can handle?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, filter, dust

I want to determine the maximum MPR (or MERV) rating that our HVAC/furnace can safely handle.

We have allergic rhinitis that worsened after moving to this high-pollution, dusty city.  There is extensive information on the internet about the MERV or MPR rating that is recommended for allergies - most from sites selling filters, but also from more impartial sites [like the EPA](https://www.epa.gov/indoor-air-quality-iaq/guide-air-cleaners-home).

Ideally we would get a HEPA filter, but after reading, I learned that it can place too great a burden on the HVAC system, and that I need to find out what my specific HVAC unit can handle.

I went through [the manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/747672/Carrier-Base-24aba3.html?page=1#manual) for our Carrier 24ABA3 48A 300 (the model # on the machine has "100 300 1A" instead of the "300"), and it does not specify.  I have extensively searched online, but cannot find a correlation between its SEER rating and MPR/MERV, either.  I saw [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8090/how-can-i-determine-which-merv-filters-would-be-best-for-my-air-handler), but the answer was for a different unit, and the link is broken.

How can I find out what MERV or MPR rating to use for this HVAC?

Comment: A lot of it depends on your ducts as well....can you provide information on the static pressure needed to move air through your HVAC system?

Comment: That is the manual for the outside condenser. You have a split system so you need the manual for the inside blower to get the duct design limits.